# How may I return a date in format YYYYMMDD using JQuery DatePicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to implement the [JQuery DatePicker w/ week no](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#show-week) and returning the selected date in format YYYYMMDD. When looking into the [api for how to format date](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) it says this could be done by using dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd". However, I'm not able to return the date in specified format.

I'm able to return the date in 'original format' with this code:

```
$(function DatePicker() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date)    {
    var date = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' );
    alert(date);
( 'getDate' ).getDate();
    },      
    showWeek: true,
    //showOn:"button",
    firstDay: 1
 });
});
```

Here is my code for trying to return (show a pop up) wewith the format 'YYYYMMDD':

```
$(function DatePicker() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
//  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function()    {
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        //var dateFormat = $(this).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat" );
        //$.(this).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd"); //Senast insatt
        alert(dateFormat);
    },      
    showWeek: true,
    firstDay: 1
});
```

});

Obviously I'm new to JQuery, and fairly new to JavaScript as a language.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to place dateFormat Out of "onSelect" function like this. `$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', onSelect: function....});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yymmdd',
      onSelect: function(v){
        alert(v);
      },      
      showWeek: true,
      firstDay: 1
});
```

`Test code here`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOBwLo

Comment: Mark it as [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it was useful.